# proof in sequent calculus LK

Tags: logic, sequent-calculus

I was reading a book that uses sequent calculus (and calls than Natural deduction  )  and that mentions as rules

$$\frac{X,A\vdash B}{X\vdash A\to B}$$

and

$$
\frac{\begin{align}X &\vdash A\to B\\ Y& \vdash A\end{align}}{X,Y\vdash B}
$$

I wanted to rewrite proof from this book to an original sequent calculus proof in the original sequent calculus  (Gentzens LK system)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus
http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN002375508

the rule $\to I$ above is in Gentzen's system FES or in modern language $\to R$

but the rule $\to E$ does not exist

How to derive $\to E$ in LK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method could be to use cut. (Forgive me, as far as I know, mathSE doesn't have a good way to type out sequent proof trees, so I'll just have to describe the tree.)

Suppose in your proof, you've derived both $X \vdash A \rightarrow B$ and $Y \vdash A$. Then using $\wedge R$ (and commutativity), you can derive $X, Y \vdash A \wedge (A \rightarrow B)$. Now, in a separate tree, start with the identities $A \vdash A$ and $B \vdash B$. Then, using $\rightarrow L$ (where $\Sigma$ and $\Delta$ are empty), we get $A, A \rightarrow B \vdash B$. By $\wedge L$ and contraction, you can then derive $A \wedge (A \rightarrow B) \vdash B$ (to do this, use $\wedge L_1$ to get $A \wedge (A \rightarrow B), A \rightarrow B \vdash B$, and then $\wedge L_2$ to get $A \wedge (A \rightarrow B), A \wedge (A \rightarrow B) \vdash B$; then use contraction). Finally, using cut on these two trees (where again $\Sigma$ and $\Delta$ are empty), you get $X, Y \vdash B$.

Now of course, by Cut Elimination, one could get a proof without using cut, but this proof tree is relatively simple because of the use of cut. Commutativity is needed if you want the order to be $X, Y$, though I imagine this wasn't a main issue. Contraction was used, but if you have an intensional conjunction in your system (as logics which reject contraction sometimes do), then the proof can be easily modified. So this proof still holds in quite a few Gentzen systems apart from LK.

Comment: Thanks this far, but the bit "A,A→B⊢B. By ∧L, you can then derive A∧(A→B)⊢B" is invalid

Comment: Ah, good point, thanks. I just fixed it. The proof now also involves contraction.

Comment: Thanks, how would a proof without contraction look?, also I am not sure about your comment about cut elimination, (i see it mentioned often) but as LK has no "remove connective" rule, how could you have a proof without cut? (i still don't understand this bit about LK)

Comment: The proof of cut elimination is rather involved, and it's a super important one in proof theory, so if you're interested you ought to have a look at some intro proof theory book. A proof without cut would probably be rather complex, which is why cut is so great.

As for a proof without contraction, some proof systems for instance add an intensional conjunction $\circ$ which has as its left rule: $A, B \vdash C$ implies $A \circ B \vdash C$, which is what I was trying to do originally with $\wedge L$. If something like this rule is allowed for $\wedge$, the proof will go through.

Comment: thank for the last comments as well

Answer (score 2):

You can see Sara Negri & Jan von Plato, *Structural Proof Theory* (2001), Ch.8 : *Back to Natural Deduction* for a very useful discussion of the relation between :

> derivability relation of single succedent sequent calculus, written $\Gamma \Rightarrow C$,

and

> derivability relation of natural deduction, written $\Gamma \vdash C$.

Natural deduction rule $\rightarrow$-I :

> $$\frac {\frac {[A]} B } {A \rightarrow B}$$

may be rewritten in "sequent form" as :

> $$\frac {\Gamma \cup \{ A \} \vdash B } {\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B}$$

With this form, the comparison with sequent calculus rule $\rightarrow$-right is easy :

> $$\frac {A, \Gamma \Rightarrow \Delta, B } {\Gamma \Rightarrow \Delta, A \rightarrow B}$$

With natural deduction rule $\rightarrow$-E, things are a little bit more complicated.

The "standard" rule :

> $$ \frac{A \rightarrow B \quad \quad A}{B}$$

may be rewritten in "sequent form" (as in your question) as :

> $$ \frac{\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B \quad \quad \Delta \vdash A}{\Gamma,\Delta\vdash B}$$

Negri & von Plato consider the $\rightarrow$-E rule in a more general form :

$$ \frac{\vdash A \rightarrow B\ \quad \Gamma \vdash A \quad B \vdash C}{C}$$

Now, we can see the connection with the sequent calculus rule $\rightarrow$-left :

> $$\frac {\Gamma_1 \Rightarrow A \quad \quad B, \Gamma_2 \Rightarrow C } {A \rightarrow B, \Gamma_1, \Gamma_2 \Rightarrow C }$$

Comment: Dear Mauro - Of course, I see your fine contribution on MSE, especially with regard to matters logical. May I impose on you for some advice. I have to some extent studied logic, but as a self-studier, am always looking to enhance my understanding of things I've already looked at. In another comment I saw you recommended Kunen's "Foundations." And, no doubt you are familiar with Boolos & al. "Computability and Logic," where there is an emphasis on sequent calculus and Gentzen-type material. How important is sequent calculus? (cont)

Comment: Does it come up a lot, or is it more specialized, and perhaps I would be better off focusing on Kunen. Thanks and kind regards,

Comment: @Andrew - sequent calculus is quite "peculiar": more suited for proof theory. You can see some of it introduced into Jan von Plato, [Elements of Logical Reasoning](https://books.google.it/books?id=8RUOAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover). Boolos & co. is a very good book, but it uses seq calc only for a small part and, IMO, this specific topic is not very clearly treated.

Comment: Thanks - That's great advice. Really appreciate it.